# How to get the width of text using Pygame

Tags: python, fonts, width, pygame

I'm using python with pygame and trying to get the width of text. The pygame documentation says to use `pygame.font.Font.size()`. However I don't understand what the function is supposed to take. I keep getting errors saying 
`TypeError: descriptor 'size' requires a 'pygame.font.Font' object but received a 'str'.`

my code I'm using to get the size and blit looks like this

```
text=self.font.render(str(x[0]), True, black)
size=pygame.font.Font.size(str(x[0]))
```

or 
`size=pygame.font.Font.size(text))`

(both give an error)

It is then blitted with
`screen.blit(text,[100,100])`

Basically I'm trying to create a function that can center or wrap text and need to be able to get the width.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the Pygame docs say `size(text) -> (width, height)`

so once you've created your font object you can use `size(text)` to dtermine how large that text is going to be in that particular font once its rendered

In your case your font object is `self.font`, so to determine the size it will be do this:

```
text_width, text_height = self.font.size("txt") #txt being whatever str you're rendering
```

then you can use those two integers to determine wher you need to place your rendered text before you actually render it

Comment: What kind/version of pygame do you use? With my pygame 1.9.3, `pygame.size()` produces "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'size'"

Comment: @Apostolos It's not `pygame.size()`. It's `font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)` and then `width, height = font.size("some text here")`

Comment: I know, I know. One and half years, since I had the question, were more than enough time to find this out! :)

Answer (score 16):

A rendered text is just a surface. You can therefore use something like: surface.get_width() resp. surface.get_height().

Here an example of having a text blitted in the very centre of your display; note: screen_width and screen_height are width and height of the display. I presume you know them.

```
my_text = my_font.render("STRING", 1, (0, 0, 0))
text_width = my_text.get_width()
text_height = my_text.get_height()

screen.blit(my_text, (screen_width // 2 - text_width // 2, screen_height // 2 - text_height // 2)
```